# How do I get a specific value from a nested object in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests

Json response returned is

```
{
 'uniqueReference': 'UV2T495QCP',
 'terminal': '0000001',
 'operator': 'Python',
 'order': {
           'orderId': 'TEST',
           'currency': 'GBP',
           'totalAmount': 0.01
          },
 'customerAccount': {
                     'cardType': 'Debit MasterCard',
                     'maskedPan': '510000******0001',
                     'expiryDate': '0129', 'entryMethod': 'KEYED'
                    }
}
```

Using requests when I run

```
response = requests.request("post", url, json=payload, headers=headers)
res = response.json()
uniqueReference = res.get('uniqueReference')
cardType = res.get('cardType')
```

I get the uniqueReference value back but `None` for cardType.

When I change to `cardType = res.get('customerAccount')` I get the full object.

I just want the value of cardType within customerAccount

Comment: Why did you not try using `.get('cardType')` with the object that was returned by `.get('customerAccount')` instead of with the original `res` object?

Comment: Side-note: There is no reason to use `.get` unless you're unsure as to whether the relevant key(s) will exist, and the lack of the keys is not an error condition. Otherwise, just use bracketed access on `dict`s, e.g. `thedict["foo"]["bar"]`.

Comment: cardType = res['customerAccount']['cardType']

Comment: Will `cardType = res['customerAccount']['cardType']` return `None`  if it doesn't exist?

Comment: If ```customerAccount``` does not exist, then ```res['customerAccount']``` will result in runtime KeyError. If you are unsure, you could either >> check whether the key exists like ```if 'customerAccount' in res and 'cardType' in res['customerAccount']: then do stuff``` or >> use try except to handle KeyError like
```try:
cardType = res['customerAccount']['cardType']
except KeyError:
HANDLE EXCEPTION STUFF HERE```